# Combining dataTracks in Gviz by averaging or subtraction

Tags: r, gviz

I would like to average (and maybe also additional operations such as subtraction) 2 or more DataTracks and plot the result using the Gviz (https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Gviz.html) package.

Say I have:

```
chr="chr2"
gen="mm10"
from=1000
to=5000

dTrep1 <- DataTrack(range = path/to/rep1.bw, genome = gen, 
             name = "bigWig",chromosome = chr)
dTrep2 <- DataTrack(range = path/to/rep2.bw, genome = gen, 
             name = "bigWig",chromosome = chr)
```

Instead of:

```
plotTracks(list(dTrep1,dTrep2),type="polygon",from=from,to=to)
```

I would like to:

```
plotTracks(mean(dTrep1,dTrep2),type="polygon",from=from,to=to)
```

Or:

```
plotTracks(dTrep1-dTrep2,type="polygon",from=from,to=to)
```

See posted also at: https://support.bioconductor.org/p/9137211/

Thanks.

Comment: It might help to post this on the [BioConductor support forum](https://support.bioconductor.org/) and add a link to that post here, either as a comment or by editing your post and adding it in the body.